# 14.04.2 keeps freezing 15mins after start up and no screen

Tags: 14.04, grub2

Every time I turn on my desktop the bios show up then after that it is a blank screen. I restart the system and then goes in to grub menu i select ubuntu. Ubuntu is the only thing on my system. Then I put in my incryption pas and then my login pas. When i load up the system with unity it freezes in about 10 to 15 mins later.? What is going on and how to fix it. 64bit amd phenom 3core and 1gb gtx550ti graficcard. Ubuntu 14.04.2